Switching between Adapters in android
My recylerview is misbehavieng ie data of different adapters doesnt occupy space from previous adapter making data to skipp around going downwards even after calling notify datsetchange ie  :
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.project) {
    page_title.setText("Projects");
    rcNotes.setAdapter(projectAdapter);
    projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
} else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.task) {
    rcNotes.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
    taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   page_title.setText("Tasks");
    return true

Tried applying notifyDataSetChanged();but still.Is there a way to refresh the ryclerview.

So, basically, I have decided to refresh the layout, and it works perfectly
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.project) {
    page_title.setText("Projects");
    rcNotes.setLayoutManager(null);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(
            2,
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    );
    rcNotes.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    rcNotes.setAdapter(projectAdapter);
    projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
} else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.task) {
    rcNotes.setLayoutManager(null);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(
            2,
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    );
    rcNotes.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    rcNotes.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
    taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    page_title.setText("Tasks");
    return true;
}


You should never need to immediately call notifyDataSetChanged right after setting the adapter.  If that's necessary, something is very wrong with your adapter.

can I get a snippet on proper implementation,please

Proper implementation of what, exactly?  The reason you don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged after setting the adapter is that at that point, nothing has changed.  It's just the initial data set.

actually the recyclerview still holds position from previous items even though my layout has changed ie items from the new adapter will start positioning from the last item postion going foward.might be a bug not sure.
